# How do I get the URL of a request?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jeresy Jax-RS to build a web service. Now I need to get the url of the request with the port # if one exist.

So if my service runs on http://www.somelocation.com/web/services I want to capture the www.somelocation.com

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add a UriInfo parameter to your operation.  From there you can access the URL:

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Response create(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, Customer customer) {
    ...
}
```